# Extended ember app to include new route and now nothing renders

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm following an ember tutorial-

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/

and have edited it to include a new model and route. The original tutorial is a CRUD app for a collection of users. I now want to expand the app to deal with a list of subjects that these users might study. `The router.js`file now looks like this-

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('users', function(){
        this.resource('user', { path:'/:user_id' }, function(){
            this.route('edit');
        });
        this.route('create');
    });

    this.resource('subjects', function(){
    this.resource('subject', {path: '/:subject_id'}, function(){
        this.route('edit');
    });
    this.route('create');
});

});
```

(Subjects are a separate route because I want to be able to create separate routes for now)

I've added a `subjects.js` model which looks like this:

```
App.Subject = DS.Model.extend({
    name         : DS.attr(),
});

App.Subject.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'History',

}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Biology',

}];
```

a subjectsController:

```
App.SubjectsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['name'],
    sortAscending: true // false = descending
});
```

a subjectsRoute:

```
App.SubjectsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('subject');
    }
});
```

and a template in my index which looks like this:

```
<script type = "text/x-handlebars" id = "subjects">
    <ul>
        {{#each subject in controller}}
            <li>{{subject.name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

I have added all my dependencies and followed the exact same steps in the tutorial as I did for the users CRUD app described in it, but now when I go to my browser, nothing renders. Can anyone see why?

Comment: Do you receive some error in the console?

Comment: Did you change your App.IndexRoute?

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior, the only errors in the console are related to the ember-data and bootstrap dependencies

Comment: @kertap, I dont have an App.IndexRoute file? Should I? The app worked fine until I started adding in new things.

Comment: @bookthief and what is the console errors of ember-data?

Comment: I got it to work, I was just missing a {/link-to}! Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tutorial described for you, there is a `missing` route to catch wrong paths, and redirect to the `users` route, maybe you need to include it to show something, since there isn't a `index` route to show some initial page.

Update your code with the following:

**router.js**

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('users', function(){
    this.resource('user', { path:'/:user_id' }, function(){
      this.route('edit');
    });
    this.route('create');
  });

  this.resource('subjects', function(){
    this.resource('subject', {path: '/:subject_id'}, function(){
        this.route('edit');
    });
    this.route('create');
  });

  // this is our 404 error route - see MissingRoute just bellow
  this.route('missing', { path: '/*path' });    
});

// this handles wrong routes - you could use it to redirect to a 404 route or like here to redirect to the index page
App.MissingRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    redirect: function(){
        this.transitionTo('users.index');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but nothing is rendering!